# How to prevent Cocos2d V3 from stopping music playing in a background app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want a user to be able to:

1) Start playing music in any app (Music, Beats, Spotify etc)

2) Open my Cocos2d V3 game

3) Still have the music from the other app (Music, Beats, Spotify etc) playing.

By default, Cocos2d V3 fades the music down and stops it.

I tried looking in the AppDelegate method – setupCocos2dWithOptions:, but there isn't anything in the options you pass in that controls audio.

Comment: please, show how you are playing your sounds...

Comment: docs for cocos2d audio engine: http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried myself, but some time ago I came across the `allowIpod` property, which should do what you need.

Try this one:

```
[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance].allowIpod = YES;
```

Note that it doesn't work on the simulator (according to the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

The docs are a bit confusing as both OALSimpleAudio and OALAudioSession implements `allowIpod`, but only the latter seems to work:

```
OALAudioSession *session = [OALAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setAllowIpod:YES];
[session setUseHardwareIfAvailable:NO];
[session setHonorSilentSwitch:YES];
```

The first should stop the iPod music from fading. The second allows the user to start iPod music after the game is opened.